# binding a dictionary to a repeater using <a> tag

Tags: asp.net

```
      <asp:Repeater ID="rptAlbum" runat="server">
            <ItemTemplate>
                 <a runat="server" href="<%# DataBinder.Eval("key"))  %>" rel='lightbox[<%#Eval("value") %>]'>
                    <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%#Eval("key") %>' Width="30px" Height="30px"/>
                 </a>
            </ItemTemplate>
      </asp:Repeater>
```

I try many way to catch the key of the dictionary into my href but allways give me answer that server tag not well formed or a string doesn't have the property of key .. :s

If someone could help me it would be very helpfull :)

best regards

Answer (score 2):

Your outer quotes where wrong:

```
  <asp:Repeater ID="rptAlbum" runat="server">
        <ItemTemplate>
             <a runat="server" href='<%# DataBinder.Eval("key"))  %>' rel='lightbox[<%#Eval("value") %>]'>
                <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%#Eval("key") %>' Width="30px" Height="30px"/>
             </a>
        </ItemTemplate>
  </asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: Not really, the error is because of quotes, once fixed it exposes new errors with how the controls are nested.  Stay possitive.

Answer (score 0):

you **can't** use that : since its **a** with **runat server.** it cant contains another yellow code in it ( only in the internal text of it)

```
  <a  href="<%# DataBinder.Eval("key"))  %>" rel='lightbox[<%#Eval("value") %>]'>
                    <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%#Eval("key") %>' Width="30px" Height="30px"/>
  </a>
```

important  :

this is **fine** :

```
 <a runat="server " >
                     <%# DataBinder.Eval("lalala"))  %>
      </a>
```

this is **wrong**

```
<a runat="server "        something='<%# DataBinder.Eval("lalala"))  %>'  > //here is the error - it contains a yellow code inside the runat server DECLARATION of the element
                     <%# DataBinder.Eval("lalala"))  %>
      </a>
```

Comment: So i need to use a <asp:Hyperlink/> tag ??

Comment: no  , you just need to remove the `tunat=server` from the `<a` declaration.

Comment: try that : `<asp:Repeater ID="rptAlbum" runat="server">
            <ItemTemplate>
                 <a   href="<%# DataBinder.Eval("key"))  %>" rel='lightbox[<%#Eval("value") %>]'>
                    <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%#Eval("key") %>' Width="30px" Height="30px"/>
                 </a>
            </ItemTemplate>
      </asp:Repeater>`

Comment: also try to remove the runatserver image from the a , I dont remember if its possible I think yes but im not sure. there is no point to put in a repeater a  runatserver items unless you want to acces them via itemDataBound Event....

Comment: i came back on the error that a System.String doesn't contain a property key however its a dictionary that i bind :

Comment: what your main goal ? what you are trying to do ?

Comment: my goal is to display a list of images then when you click on one of them, it results the display of a lightbox whith the image inside.

Comment: Basically thats what i have : > <a rel="lightbox[event01]" href="/Portals/0/Photos/Event01/EC2_1472.jpg"><img alt="" src="/Portals/0/Photos/Event01/EC2_1472.jpg" /></a>

Comment: But it is not dynamic ... so i need to use this repeater :)

Comment: I dont have an issue with the repeater. your code didnt compile since you used `a` with runatserver and near it you used yellow code which is also server. thats was your question - this was my answer. If you have another problem - so open a new question :) you had a basic problem with the run at server - the dictionarry stuff its another question